# Custom Attribtues - No SQL Data Store

Tags: nosql

We want to develop a application which need to support custom attribtues to different entities (like user, project, folder, document etc..) in our application.

I googled and prima face it looks like No-SQL database can be suited for our requirement. Do you see any limitation ? What are the prons/cons of using No-SQL instead of RDBMS?

There are many NO-SQL databases available - http://nosql-database.org/ ? But we don't have any experiance in using No SQL database.Don't find any good article which compares these NO-SQL database. Any suggestion which No-SQL data store we can use to achive custom attribtues functionality?

Answer (score 1):

One big advantage of No-sql database is its free-style: you will never specify the columns like "user, project, folder" before you insert your real data. The columns can be added at any time.

While in RDBMS, the table schema is strictly defined, can not modify during run time.

Another advantage is the performance in query. It is quite efficient if you query all the records of a user, say "Michael", since the data is stored following the principle of Big Table, named by google.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your question: a column database such as Cassandra; or a name-value pair (also called attribute-value pair) in relational.

First, Cassandra is a structured key-value store. A key can contain multiple and variable attributes and values. Values or columns are grouped into column families. The column families are fixed when a Cassandra database is created. A family is analogous to an entity in a logical data model or to a table in relational. Columns can be added to a family at any time. Thereby, different instances of the column family can have different columns, which is what you need. Furthermore, columns are assigned to specified keys, so different keys can have different numbers of columns in any given family.

A name value pair, also called an attribute value pair, can be created in logical data modeling and in relational. This can be done with three related entities or tables:

- The base entity (such as customer), which in analogous to a column family.
- A "type" entity, which describes the attribute and its characteristics such as Net Worth Amount,
- A "value" entity, which assigns the attribute to an instance of a base entity and assigns it a value.

The "type" entity is simply a code table identified by a type code and containing a description and other domain characteristics. Domain refers to data type, length, meaning, and units of measure. It describes the attribute out of context (i.e., unassigned). An example could be Net Worth Amount, which is a number 8 digits with 2 decimal places, right justified, and its description is "a value representing the total financial value of a customer including liquid and non-liquid amounts".

The "value" entity is an associative entity or table that is identified by the customer id and the attribute type code, and has a value attribute that assigns the Net Worth Amount type the Customer and gives it a value, such as "$2,000,000."

However, in relational name-value pairs are somewhat difficult to query in SQL and generally do not perform well. This could be addressed by denormalizing the "type" and "value" entities into one. Instead of having three tables you have two -- one-to-many. Actually, that is essentially how Cassandra does it. A column family is a fully flattened attribute-value pair.

I hope this helps. If you are going to use NOSQL, I'd use something like Cassandra. If you use relational, I'd denormalize (i.e., collapse into one) the type and value. The advantage of relational is that your already have it. The disadvantage to Cassandra is that you have to learn it but it is build to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase would be a great answer for you, if you can encapsulate your model into JSON then you are already halfway there. You can have any number of properties for your object:

product::001
{
  "name": "Hard Drive",
  "brand": "Toshiba",
   ...
   ...
}

To learn some simple patterns moving from RDBMS to Couchbase, check out their webinars at http://www.couchbase.com/webinars or some simple design patterns at http://CouchbaseModels.com (examples are in Ruby though)

The real advantage of Couchbase is schema flexibility, horizontal scalability on commodity hardware, and speed. After learning the basics, it fits better into Agile processes, with almost no need for migrations. In enterprise organizations it's very effective since every column modification will require business processes and approvals with the DBA. Couchbase schema flexibility circumvents a lot of these issues.